# Increase accuracy of mysql query

Tags: mysql, join

Is there is any way of increasing the accuracy of the following query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.localgeo, a.foreigngeo, b.lat, b.lng, c.lat, c.lng
FROM tbl_correlateddata a
JOIN tbl_geodetail b ON a.localgeo = b.code
JOIN tbl_geodetail c ON a.foreigngeo = c.code
```

I am accessing a table with 2 country codes

```
localgeo|foreigngeo
--------------------
JP      |AD
JP      |AD
US      |HK
AD      |JP
HK      |US
AD      |JP
CN      |US
```

and trying to fill it with longitude and latitude values from another table

```
code|lat|lng
------------
JP  |1  |2
US  |3  |3
HK  |1  |4
AD  |3  |4
CN  |4  |4
```

The result looks like this

```
localgeo|lat|lng|foreigngeo |lat|lng|
------------------------------------
JP      |1  |2  |AD         |3  |4
US      |3  |3  |HK         |1  |4
HK      |1  |4  |US         |3  |3
AD      |3  |4  |JP         |1  |2
CN      |4  |4  |US         |3  |3
```

but the query takes alot of time. Is there any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you are using distinct for all fields ,you didnt make `()`, and it take very much time . try to use distinct only for one column

like this

```
    SELECT DISTINCT (a.localgeo), a.foreigngeo, b.lat, b.lng, c.lat, c.lng
    FROM tbl_correlateddata a 
    JOIN tbl_geodetail b 
      ON a.localgeo = b.code 
    JOIN tbl_geodetail c 
      ON a.foreigngeo = c.code
```

EDIT:

```
     SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM t
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
     SELECT a,b,c FROM t GROUP BY a,b,c
```

so you should do like that

```
     SELECT a.localgeo, a.foreigngeo, b.lat, b.lng, c.lat, c.lng
    FROM tbl_correlateddata a 
    JOIN tbl_geodetail b 
      ON a.localgeo = b.code 
    JOIN tbl_geodetail c 
      ON a.foreigngeo = c.code
     GROUP BY a.localgeo ,a.foreigngeo
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, but the issue is i need both the columns to be distinct..as there cannot be repetitie combinations in the result i get..as in `DISTINCT (a.localgep, a.foreigngeo)` but this is not possible..is there a workaround to do this??

Comment: look my edit ,dont use distinct and use group by your columns wich u want to be distinct

Comment: ohh yess...thats the thing..`GROUP BY` does it nicely :) thank you very much